# Pytorch :Why my dataset variance do not get the correct result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Here is the function I wrote:

```
def channel_var(image_dataset):
    res = image_dataset[0]
    for image in image_dataset[1:]:
        res += image
    return tuple(map(lambda x: x/len(image_dataset),
     (torch.var(res[0]),
      torch.var(res[1]),
      torch.var(res[2]))))
```

then I tested it with a Normal distribution :

```
m = normal.Normal(0, 3)
m.sample((1, 3, 32, 32))
```

And I get this wrong result :

```
channel_var(list_test)

>>(tensor(0.0338), tensor(0.0352), tensor(0.0365))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your function is wrong. And that's because you are computing the average image and then computing the channel variance in the average image. I don't think you want that. You can just find the variance in each channel by using

`torch.var(img, dim=[0,2,3])`

assuming `dim=1` is the channel dimension and img is a torch tensor. If img is not a torch tensor, you can concatenate list of imgs to make a tensor.

You can do this as `torch.var(torch.cat(img, dim=0), dim=[0,2,3])` `cat` operation concatenates list to a tensor.